# dropping all the columns after a matching value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the below data frame

[image]

and i have a variable as `ID = 1052107168068132864`

How I can filter all the values to drop it after that column and can get the result like below. In a way i want to drop all the column after that Id including it as well.
[image]

and then update the value of `ID` as `1052121282324692992` as the current value.
i want to repeat this in a loop so that every time i get a new data frame the same operation will keep going and if that is the top value then nothing should happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `ID`s are unique, using `iloc`

```
df.iloc[:df[df.ID == '1052121282324692992'].index.item()]
```

Comment: how i can repeat it in a loop for the new incoming value

Comment: and what if the data is not properly indexed and is filtered

Answer (score 0):

Using idxmax

```
idx = (df['ID'] == ID).idxmax()
new_df = df.iloc[:idx, :]
```

Comment: how i can make it dynamic say if new ids are coming then deleting the old ones and setting ID for the last deleted one and keep on repeating it.

Comment: Would you want rows between old and new ID or all the rows from beginning upto the new ID?

Comment: i am creating a tweet alert..suppose iam tweeting having words like hate in it then i will send that tweet as email and then store the tweet id and then next time i want to check if thats the same tweet then i dont want to send the notification and if there are tweets with word hate then i dont want to consider the old one and delete it and send the new one as email.......do i make sense? i want to keep repeating that all the time . LONG STORY SHORT so just new Id and remove all the tweet with old Id and before that

Comment: Not very clear about what do you want. Can you post your sample dataframe and desired output - not in the form of image?

Comment: @Vaishali-- how can i achieve the one you asked -- Would you want rows between old and new ID or all the rows from beginning upto the new ID? – Vaishali

Comment: how can i achieve it without taking help of index... that is what i want

Comment: the above solution is also only workign if the index is in a serial way.